# PDO : How different is mysql from postgresql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

I want to use Mysql on my local and PostgreSQL on production server. How difficult is it. I am mysql novice and have no idea on PostgreSQL. I will be using just crud with joins. My coding is in PHP PDO so hope there is no problem there. Also is there a SIMPLE beginners guide to postgresql

Comment: One's a Ford card, the other's a GM car. Both will get you where you're going, but all the knobs/dials/console displays will be in different places.

Comment: One option would be to use an ORM like Doctrine to abstract away the differences between the databases.

Comment: **Never** use a different DBMS between development and production.

Comment: A simple web search will show you all the Postgres documentation you'll ever need. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/ Here's a second vote on *never* using a different brand of database on your production-server: like racing for pole-position in a GM, then racing the Indy-500 in a Ford!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want to use Mysql on my local and PostgreSQL on production server.

No, you dont, you really don't - trust me.

> I am mysql novice and have no idea on PostgreSQL.

Then pick one and stick with it. You'll have enough to manage learning one system. Both run on all the usual platforms you might meet and PostgreSQL runs on loads you probably never will. Making sure your application works on both RDBMSs will be fiddly and bug-prone.

I'd recommend PostgreSQL - it's more strict (irritating at first, pays off later) and has better standards support and advanced query planning. Having said that though, if you've only got MySQL on both systems just use that.

Comment: Agree. The most effords of a server administrator is to keep the same version of softwares between production and test machine;
Using _A_ for test and _B_ for production is a debugging nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

To give you a bit more of a general answer..

Most standard queries are almost the same. There are slight differences though, so there is no guarantee that a query you write for mysql, will also just work for postgres.

You are much better off to make your production and development environment identical.